# Scrollbar on ul disabled when in IE, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a UL tag within Google MDL to provide a popup menu on an input. The following is the CSS

```
    .ie-specific{
        -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;
        max-height:300px;
    }
```

and the HTML Markup

```
            <div class="page-content">
                <!-- Specialty Selection -->
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
                    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
                        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield">
                            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="Specialty">
                            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2">Specialty</label>
                            <div class="">
                                <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect ie-specific" for="Specialty" id="SpecialtyList" style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height:300px;">

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the UL is built by a JS Query which takes the result of a query and uses that to build up the options;

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetSpecialties.ashx",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                var parent = document.getElementById("SpecialtyList");

                data.forEach(function(el) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    var liClass = document.createAttribute("class");

                    liClass.value = "mdl-menu__item"
                    li.setAttributeNode(liClass);

                    li.innerText = el.Name;
                    parent.appendChild(li);
                    componentHandler.upgradeDom(parent);
                });


            }
        });
    });
```

Trouble is while in Google Chrome I get the scrollbar and can use it to scroll through the options; in IE the scrollbar is disabled and you cannot scroll to see the later options.

I'm using a combination of JQuery and Google Material Design Light

Comment: Create a fiddle with hard coded values.

Comment: Fiddle can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/mys23aob/ - note you cannot edit in IE but it does demonstrate the problem